# referencing a KeyVault secret in an ARM template fails with 'The resource is not defined in the template'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a KeyVault reference in the AppConfig section of an Azure web app.
The KeyVault reference references a secret which exists in a KeyVault which is part of a different resourcegroup and thus does not exist in the template.

according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference) of the reference() template function you should be able to reference a resource which is not part of the template as long as you provide the complete resourceId and the apiVersion.

But when I use that to reference the secret I keep getting a validation error which says:

> Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation
>   failed: 'The resource
>   'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults//secrets/' is not
>   defined in the template.

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#reference-syntax). for how to use KeyVault references in ARM templates.

Below code is a sample of a situation which does not work.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
  "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('serverFarmName'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "alwaysOn": true,
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "<secretName>",
          "value": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('secretResourceId')).secretUriWithVersion, ')')]"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('serverFarmName'))]"
  ]
}
```

The variable is defined like this:

```
"variables": {
  "secretResourceId": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, parameters('keyVaultResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', parameters('keyVaultName'), 'secretName')]"
},
```

Is this something specific to references to KeyVault secrets?

As soon as I try the same but with a keyvault and secret inside the template it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for the [`reference` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference) mentions that the second parameter to the function, `apiVersion` is required when the referring resource isn't provisioned within the same template.

So, instead of

```
reference(variables('secretResourceId')).secretUriWithVersion
```

something like this should work

```
reference(variables('secretResourceId'), '2018-02-14').secretUriWithVersion
```

Comment: Thanks PramodValavala-MSFT, I missed that part in the docs. That did the trick.