# Azure ARM template deployment failure with error Invalid Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

Status: Failed
Error:
Code: InvalidTemplate
Message: Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvaultName/secrets/' at line '788' and column '5'. 'The language expression property 'AliasPrimaryConnectionString' doesn't exist, available properties are 'primaryConnectionString, secondaryConnectionString, primaryKey, secondaryKey, keyName'.

The weird thing is that it was working till a week back and we havent made any changes to the template. Logging in to the portal too able to see the AliasPrimaryConnectionString being present in serviceBus access policies as a SAS key. Not sure why template deployment is complaining it cannt find it. The Api Version being used is 2017-04-01.

The relevant template snippet:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "name": "[concat(variables('AppKVName'), '/DeviceOrchestrationServiceBusSendKey', if(equals(copyIndex(), 0), '', copyIndex()))]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[variables('AppKVName')]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "value": "[replace(listKeys(resourceId(variables('StorageSubscriptionId'), variables('StorageResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/authorizationRules',concat(variables('AppServiceBusName'), if(equals(copyIndex(), 0), '', copyIndex())), variables('DeviceOrchestrationTopic'), variables('SendAccessKey')), variables('ServiceBusApiVersion')).AliasPrimaryConnectionString,';EntityPath=deviceorchestrationtopic', '')]"
  },
  "copy": {
    "name": "DeviceOrchestrationServiceBusSendKeyCopy",
    "count": "[variables('PartitionCountDeviceOrchestration')]"
  }
},
```

Comment: Could you share the ARM template with us please ? or at least relevant parts of it

Comment: is AliasPrimaryConnectionString still available in the KeyVault? And is its value set?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for looking.
Shared the relevant arm template. 
@CharlieV  AliasPrimaryConnectionString is available in ServiceBus SAS keys, since we have geo DR enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the above issue we can follow the below workaround:

As mentioned in this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference):-

> ```
> reference(resourceName or resourceIdentifier, [apiVersion], ['Full'])
> ```
>
> *This parameter is required when the resource isn'tprovisioned within same template. Typically, in the format, yyyy-mm-dd*

- So please *Make sure that When referring resource is not supplied within the same template, the function's second parameter, `apiVersion` need to mention which is necessary* .

For example:-

```
variables('resourcename'), '2018-02-14').AliasPrimaryConnectionString
```

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59875280/referencing-a-keyvault-secret-in-an-arm-template-fails-with-the-resource-is-not) .